# Using the Putzer Algorithm to Compute $e^{At}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

[image]

I'm having trouble with a certain step in computing the Putzer algorithm. See the image below for the step at which my problem occurs.

Comment: Note that the box defining $p'$ misses a $p$ after the matrix. That system lets you calculate $p_1(t)$, plug in and solve for $p_2(t)$, plug in and solve for $p_3(t)$ etc. The plugged-in solutions go to the right-hand side of the ODEs.

Comment: How do we obtain that $p_1(t) = e^{t}$ and $p_2(t)=\frac{1}{4}(e^{5t}-e^{t})$?

Comment: Simply write the matrix system as individual ODEs.